# Unrecognized key(s) in object: 'images' at "experimental" - Next.js 14.1.0 error

Tags: next.js

I am trying to host my nextJs project to github pages and I was watching a tutorial. I am trying to run a pipeline in github but I get this error message. this is all the code in my next.config.mjs:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {};

export default nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the setup pages step from the workflow

```
- name: Setup Pages
    uses: actions/configure-pages@v4
    with:
      # Automatically inject basePath in your Next.js configuration file and disable
      # server side image optimization (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#unoptimized).
      #
      # You may remove this line if you want to manage the configuration yourself.
      static_site_generator: next
```